# Showing a div with display property but hidden by default

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wish to have a div hidden by default and am having problems with the following JavaScript code.

The code is somewhat working but it initially shows the div and then hides it instead of hiding it first and then showing it at the click of a button.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x=document.getElementById("answers");
  if (x.style.display==="none") {
    x.style.display="block";
  }
  else {
    x.style.display="none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="sendButton" onclick="myFunction()">Send</button>
<p id="answers">Answers</p>
```

Comment: "_having problems with jQuery_" There is no jQuery in your code.

Comment: https://jquery.com/ - in addition to Ivar's comment, you can check what jQuery is here. You are using just plain JavaScript.

Comment: Yes @Ivar, that's why I'm not using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the initial value for hiding the `DIV`

```
style="display:none"
```

**See demo**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("answers");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="sendButton" onclick="myFunction()">Send</button>

<!-- add the initial value for hiding the div -->
<div id="answers" style="display:none">answers here</div>
```

Comment: was about to propose the same, one could also separate the styling in external CSS if the OP is not a fan of inline styles

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple ternary operator - also, setting `style.display = ""` will show the element:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("answers");
    x.style.display = x.style.display == "none" ? "" : "none";
}
```

You also need to add `style="display: none;"` to your `<div>` element if you want it to be hidden by default:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("answers");
  x.style.display = x.style.display == "none" ? "" : "none";
}
```

```html
<button id="sendButton" onclick="myFunction()">Send</button>

<div id="answers" style="display: none;">This is some text.</div>
```

Comment: Sorry @Ivar, I'll fix that.

Comment: No problem @Tommmm, I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your current script works fine. Just add the CSS property `display: none` to your `#answers` element to initially hide it by default:

```
<p id="answers" style="display:none">
  Answers
</p>
```

Also, you should avoid using inline on-* handlers (onclick, oninput, on change, etc) and use event listeners instead.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example with the above css code:

### INLINE CSS:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("sendButton");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var x=document.getElementById("answers");
  if (x.style.display==="none") {
    x.style.display="block";
  }
  else {
    x.style.display="none";
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="sendButton">Send</button>
<p id="answers" style="display:none">Answers</p>
```

### EXTERNAL CSS:

```js
/* JavaScript */

const btn = document.getElementById("sendButton");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var x=document.getElementById("answers");
  if (window.getComputedStyle(x).display === "none") {
    x.style.display="block";
  }
  else {
    x.style.display="none";
  }
});
```

```css
/* CSS */

#answers {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<button id="sendButton">Send</button>
<p id="answers">Answers</p>
```

---

**N.B.** You can shorten the above code using a ternary operator as shown in @JackBashford's answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, will try it out

Answer (score 0):

You can add initial value for hiding the div by using hidden too (HTML5 attribute).

```
<div id="answers" hidden>answers here</div>
```